# Unwanted None at the end of the Recursion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

when I try to print the all the natural numbers from 1 to n using recursion I'm getting None at the end of the result
My code

```
def num_1_to_n(n):
   if n==1:
        return n
   print(n)
   print(num_1_to_n(n-1))
n=int(input(enter the n value))
num_1_to_n(n)
```

I wanted to get

```
4
4
3
2
1
```

but I get

```
4
4
3
2
1
None
None
None
```

Can anyone please tell me the reason behind the printing of `None` after 1

Comment: If `n` isn't `1`, `num_1_to_n` doesn't `return` anything. So a few of those `print(num_1_to_n(n-1))` will print `None`.

Comment: @deceze Python will _always_ `return` something, and if the end of a function body is reached, the function automatically implicitly returns `None`. I guess that is what you really meant to say.

Comment: @deceze ok I agree with you but why it is printing None at the end. when I debug my code after reaching `0` it is again calling `print(num_1_to_n(n-1))` there n becomes its original value(4)

Comment: @karthikeyaGundumogula This statement `print(num_1_to_n(n-1))` prints the return value of that function call, which is `None`, except in case of the argument being equal to `1`. [I added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214423/1170207).

Answer (score 1):

Recursion often occurs problems like this, so use for loops:

```py
n = int(input("Enter the n value"))
for i in range(n, 1, -1):
    print(i)
print(1) # for the loop to not stop at 2
```

Or, shorter:

```py
n = int(input("Enter the n value"))
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is printing `None` because you of `print(num_1_to_n(n-1))` when you only need to call the function like `num_1_to_n(n-1)`.

Final Code:

```
def num_1_to_n(n):
   if n==1:
        print(1)
        return n

   print(n)
   num_1_to_n(n-1)

n=int(input("enter the n value"))
num_1_to_n(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
def num_1_to_n(n):
   if n==1:
       print(1)
       return n
   print(n)
   num_1_to_n(n-1)
n=int(input("enter the n value"))
num_1_to_n(n)
```

Output:

```
enter the n value4
4
3
2
1
```

you gate those none because of print(num_1_to_n(n-1)) this print

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
def num_1_to_n(n):
   if n==1:
        return n
   print(n)
   print(num_1_to_n(n-1))
```

the statement `print(num_1_to_n(n-1))` prints the return value of the function call `num_1_to_n(n-1)`. Your function returns `1` in case of `n == 1` and `None` otherwise, since [Python implicitly returns `None` when it reaches the end of a function body during execution](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) (emphasis mine):

> The return statement returns with a value from a function. return without an expression argument returns None. **Falling off the end of a function also returns None**.

So you will see three `None` for the three calls where `n != 1`, when you start at `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try it this way:

```
def num_1_to_n(n):
  if n > 1:
      print(n)
      num_1_to_n(n-1)
  else:
      print(1)

n=int(input('enter the n value: '))
num_1_to_n(n)
```